Cannot add new package to old angular 7 project
I'm trying to add a new package to my existing old project Angular 7, node version 10.15.3. but whenever i try  to do the following
npm install @angular/material@7.3.7 @angular/cdk@7.3.7 --legacy-peer-deps

(also i tried without --legacy-peer-deps) i get a whole ton of errors.
i use nvm to manage node versions depending on the project.
{
  "name": "unified",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -o",
    "start:dev": "ng serve -o -c=dev --port=4201",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^3.0.0-preview6.19307.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^0.6.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@videojs/http-streaming": "^2.13.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.23.7",
    "angular-notifier": "^6.0.1",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.2.1",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.4.1",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "angular2-lightbox": "^1.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "c3": "^0.4.18",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "cleanup-dependencies": "0.0.6",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "css-animator": "^2.1.1",
    "d3": "^4.12.0",
    "echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "esri-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "feather-icons-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome-scss": "^1.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-click-outside": "^3.0.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "ng2-archwizard": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^3.5.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.2",
    "ng2-ui-switch": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.9.8",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.0.4",
    "ngx-echarts": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.4",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-pinch-zoom": "^2.4.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-treeview": "^6.0.2",
    "nouislider": "^11.1.0",
    "recordrtc": "^5.5.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "video.js": "^7.18.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.14.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^4.1.3",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
}

6407 warn ngx-carousel@1.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6408 warn ngx-carousel@1.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.4.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6409 warn ngx-carousel@1.3.5 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6410 warn ngx-chips@1.9.8 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6411 warn ngx-chips@1.9.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6412 warn ngx-chips@1.9.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6413 warn ngx-chips@1.9.8 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6414 warn ngx-color-picker@5.3.8 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6415 warn ngx-color-picker@5.3.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6416 warn ngx-echarts@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6417 warn ngx-echarts@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || >=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6418 warn ngx-order-pipe@2.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6419 warn ngx-perfect-scrollbar@5.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6420 warn ngx-perfect-scrollbar@5.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6421 warn ngx-pinch-zoom@2.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6422 warn ngx-pinch-zoom@2.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6423 warn ngx-toastr@10.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 <9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6424 warn ngx-toastr@10.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 <9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6425 warn ngx-toastr@10.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=6.0.0 <9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6426 warn ngx-treeview@6.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6427 warn ngx-treeview@6.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6428 warn ngx-treeview@6.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6429 warn tslint@5.9.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6430 warn tsutils@2.29.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6431 warn @angular/material@7.3.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6432 warn @angular/material@7.3.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6433 warn @angular/material@7.3.7 requires a peer of @angular/animations@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6434 warn @angular/cdk@7.3.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6435 warn @angular/cdk@7.3.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
6436 verbose stack Error: Refusing to delete C:\Projects\Unified\node_modules\.bin\node-gyp.cmd: is outside C:\Projects\Unified\node_modules\node-gyp and not a link
6436 verbose stack     at clobberFail (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:121:12)
6436 verbose stack     at isSafeToRm (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:114:15)
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:54:5
6436 verbose stack     at LOOP (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:7:26)
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:18:7
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:180:7
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
6436 verbose stack     at _readAllLinks (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:215:28)
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
6436 verbose stack     at resolveSymlink (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:226:22)
6436 verbose stack     at _readAllLinks (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:217:5)
6436 verbose stack     at readAllLinks (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:212:3)
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:179:5
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
6436 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
6436 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\rm.js:153:16
6437 verbose cwd C:\Projects\Unified
6438 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22631
6439 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@angular/material@7.3.7" "@angular/cdk@7.3.7" "--legacy-peer-deps"
6440 verbose node v10.15.3
6441 verbose npm  v6.4.1
6442 error path C:\Projects\Unified\node_modules\.bin\node-gyp.cmd
6443 error code EEXIST
6444 error Refusing to delete C:\Projects\Unified\node_modules\.bin\node-gyp.cmd: is outside C:\Projects\Unified\node_modules\node-gyp and not a link
6445 error File exists: C:\Projects\Unified\node_modules\.bin\node-gyp.cmd
6446 error Move it away, and try again.
6447 verbose exit [ 1, true ]


Your npm versions are very loosely defined. For example ^7.0.0 means versions bigger them 7.0.0 and smaller then 8.0.0 If packages follow semver that should not be a problem but unfortunately this is not always true. I would suggest to go through your original lock file and use this specific version from there in you package.json. Like this you make sure you always use exactly the same version.

did you try to do what the error says: delete file C:\Projects\Unified\node_modules.bin\node-gyp.cmd and try again
